# Research internships at universities and funding

Tags: funding, research-undergraduate, internship

I'm going to graduate next summer from my bachelors. Before pursuing a masters program, I'd like to get to know research groups at different universities. Some universities seem to offer some kind of internship programs but I couldn't find any clear information.

How does it generally work? Can one do 6 months or a year of research at another university between bachelors and masters? Does it cost money and where can one find funding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends. You can join a summer REU program, where you can get funding. You can go on various websites of professor who may be advertising positions, and contact them. Keep in mind this, sometimes, the particular opportunity that you are looking for may not exist (in your case, 6 months/1 year research at a university, as a non-student). That means that you will have to contact professors (even if that means contacting tens of them), and ask them if they would be willing to consider bringing you on for that long. Obviously, you will need to offer them something, like strong computing skill (which will really distinguish you). As I looked at your profile, it seems like you do have a strong computing skill, and so I would advertise that. Another great option (which I did in my previous life), was join the IT department of a specific academic department, and slowly find the opportunity to network with faculty and let them know regarding your skills. Slowly, you will have the opportunity to possibly engage in research and strengthen your graduate school application. In life, often times you have to make your own opportunity. I wish you the best in your future endeavours.

Comment: You might find [this page](https://www.nsf.gov/crssprgm/reu/reu_search.jsp) helpful in finding an NSF REU program near or interesting (or both!!) to you.

Comment: Thank you both. I'm also fine with 3 months and it might allow me to visit more groups. From your answer it sounds like professors expect payment for those positions, is that correct?

Comment: @danijar No, it is the other way around. You want to ask them if they have the sufficient funding to pay you. Never get a position where you have to pay them (that is extremely unusual). As I said before, it seems like to are a very strong programmer, and so I would advertise this skill, because it is not easy to find programmers like you, and professors (in my experiences as a student) will really look into that possibility.

Comment: Alright, that helps a lot.

Comment: @danijar No problem. Make sure to email a lot of professors (I'm familiar with the USA especially) in labs you are interested in. Also, apply to IT positions in departments of interest. There are a lot of good opportunities, but you're going to have to create them ( I did the same, and assure you that it's not impossible). I really wish you the best.